# Replacing a reference to an observable array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to keep my data somewhat separate from my viewmodels by setting them by assignment. I'd like to replace an array and have the DOM update, as in this example:

```
demo.items = demo.items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.childMsg.match(/Hello/)
})
```

However, this is not working. Updating using `.push` and `.$remove` does work.

```
var services = [];

socket.messages.on('serviceUp', function (service) {
  localforage.getItem(service.name, function (err, local_service) {
    service = _.extend(local_service || {}, service); // Attach properties from localstorage
    services.push(service);
  });
});


socket.messages.on('serviceDown', function (service) {
  var index = _.findWhere(services, { name: service.name });
  services.$remove(index);
  // services = _.reject(services, function (item) { // This doesn't work - why?
  //   return item.name === service.name;
  // });
});


Vue.component('service-columns', {
  template: '#service-columns',
  data: {
    services: services
  },
  computed: {
    columns: {
      $get: function () {
        return columnize(this.services, 3);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A working JSFiddle might be helpful here, but I'm guessing that you could fix it by using:

`demo.$set("items", demo.items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.childMsg.match(/Hello/)
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to remove observable proto from objects and arrays.

```
const clone = (value) => {
  if (!value) return value;
  const isObject = (typeof value === 'object');
  const isArray = Array.isArray(value);
  if (!isObject && !isArray) return value;
  // Removing reference of Array of values
  if (isArray) return [...value.map(val => clone(val))];
  if (isObject) return { ...value };
  return value;
};
```